# How to select item displayed by DisplayMemberPath in wpf ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a **ComboBox** control and I am getting the **ItemsSource** of the control from a **Web Service** **(Asp.Net WebApi 2)**, the code of which is as follows:

```
cmb_Class.ItemsSource = from c in Container.Classes select new {ClassID = c.Class_Id};
cmb_Class.DisplayMemberPath = "ClassID";
```

I had used `DisplayMemberPath` so that I can only get the assigned value.

But,

The problem is that when I select an **item** from the drop down menu, instead of that item the **whole string** is shown as selected item in the Combobox.

The Image of my problem for better understanding is as follows:

[image]

Please, tell me how can I solve this issue?

Comment: I notice the colour of the text in your combo box is green. What does the xaml look like, do you have any templates that might be overriding the default style for the combobox?

Comment: Hi @LeighShepperson No it's just the `Foreground` property of combobox nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Problem is solved.

I was using the `WatermarkCombobox` control of **ExtendedWpfToolkit** when I changed it to the default wpf `Combobox` control, my problem got solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add an actual solution for the WatermarkComboBox. It appears that the WatermarkComboBox is missing a part of the XAML.

I would create a style for this ComboBox with Blend, and then under / within the line:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
```

add in the following line of XAML:

```
ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
```

This will resolve the problem.